# How to compare versions with a local file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to compare differences between two versions following these tutorials [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/comparing-versions-viewer) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/compare-two-2d-documents-using-forge-viewer) however I have local files stored in a Azure blob.

How can I use the method `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load` to load the files by a blob URL? Or use another method to compare local files?

Answer (score 0):

Try `pixelCompareExt.compareTwoViewables`:

```
pixelCompareExt.compareTwoViewables(blobURLA: string, optionsA: object|null, blobURLB: string, optionsB: object|null, onALoadSuccess?: event=>void, onBLoadSuccess?: event=>void)
```

See source for its usage in details [here](https://github.com/wallabyway/2DCompare/blob/master/docs/extensions/PixelCompare/PixelCompare.min.js#L107).

Comment: Hey @bryan-huang thanks for the answer! I tried but I'm receiving the error "F2D streaming broken by non-streaming unzip! ErrorCode:2." when the extention tries download de blob i think

Comment: Are you loading a SVF or a raw file (RVT, PDF) etc? That is not supported by the pixelCompare extension - the models would need to be translated using our Model Derivative services and loaded as derivatives (SVFs generated by the translation) downloaded to your own persistence.